# Host NodeJS server both with express and Websocket so you can send data back and forth with Flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, heroku, websocket

Hosting a NodeJS server on Heroku is completely new for me. So now I want to create a server on Heroku that can send data back and forth together with Flutter. The thing is I've no idea what address to use or what port.

This is the Index server where as you can sends data back and forth. It works fine on localhost but trying it out on Heroku is different.

index.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; //port for Heroku that works fine

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/lib/index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening at: ${PORT}`)
});

var  webSockets = {}


const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 6060 }) // Which port for Heroku?


wss.on('connection', function (ws, req)  {
        var userID = req.url.substr(1)
        console.log('User connected:', userID)
        webSockets[userID] = ws //add new user to the connection list
        ws.on('message', message => { //if there is any message
          console.log(message)
          ws.send("succes");
     }
}
```

This is the flutter function that is used to send data and receive it normally with localhost it functions like it should, but Heroku is different.

test.dart

```
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

// Changing this address to "ws://localhost:6060/user1" works completely fine on localhost
channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect('ws://example.herokuapp.com:6060/user1');
String message = "{'cmd':'This message should be sended to Heroku'}";

channel.sink.add(message);

channel.stream.listen((message) async {
   print(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you backend is independent so I dont think whether you are using flutter or ReactNative for frontend is a big deal.

As for heroku, they have pretty good docs here which you can read [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)
also remember to add this code in index Node file

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    //express will serve up production assest
    //like  our main.js or main.css files
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));

    //express will serve up index.js file if it doesn't recognizes the route
    const path = require("path");
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}
```

also this postbuild script in scripts section of node.js `package.json`

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: address would be ` https://<heroku_project_name>.herokuapp.com` and for port would be automatically choosen by heroku so you dont need to worry about that, just using address is the right way for example instead of `localhost:5000/login` use `https://<heroku_project_name>.herokuapp.com/login`

Comment: Thanks that is the answer that I needed have a good day

Comment: Your Welcome! Although can you uptick my answer and mark it as correct? It encourages individual developers like me to help people further out